# My radiator is busted in myAcura mdx

Tags: radiator, coolant-leak, acura, mdx

I hit a deer and totalled the front of my Acura MDX.it still runs and drives but the radiator has several holes in it and the cooling fans are bent and not working.This is my only car and I have to get to work and have no other options, how can I drive it without the radiator?

Comment: I once limped a car 150 miles home with a punctured radiator.  The trick was to drive slowly enough that the thermostat didn't open so that the water in the engine block didn't leak out.  Doing that every day for work isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this happened to you. You can't drive a car any significant distance without a radiator. If you have collision insurance, check your policy's declarations page to see if it will pay for a rental car while your car is being repaired.